# Reduce left-margin in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

This has been asked for 2015 but the answer seems 2015-specific.

I've turned off Tools->Options->Text Editor->General->Selection Margin and Indicator Margin but still have a 5-6 character wide white area on the left.

It wastes scant screen space, and it makes it impossible to eyeball where the start of a line is when selecting text for copy or deletion.

What other things must one turn off to turn this off?

Comment: I mentioned this to MSFT and they duly put it in their bug tracking system and after about six months or longer, they closed it as being something no-one else was complaining about and therefore too low priority.